# Docx4j - convert docx with chart to pdf (java, or c#)

Tags: java, c#, pdf, docx, docx4j

I have example docx with chart:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUblu.png)

when I run example project:
org.docx4j.samples.ConvertOutPDF

I have empty pdf.

How to convert docx with chart to pdf?
I need a free tool/library.

Comment: Word has a tool to export to pdf.

Comment: Take a look this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118633/convert-docx-file-into-pdf-with-java

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060541/creating-pdf-from-word-doc-using-apache-poi-and-itext-in-java

Comment: And something for C#?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same using [Jacob](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hynnet/jacob/1.18) - check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619098/converting-a-docx-containing-a-chart-to-pdf). Please be aware: This requires Windows OS as well as installed MS Word.

Cheers, Dominik

Edit: Docx4J has issues when converting embedded charts - you may experience this, when using the [webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/demo_landing.html) for pdf-conversion.